# Autofac with Web Forms in VB.Net throwing MissingMemberException

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, autofac

I am trying to user [Autofac](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/) in my Web Form application, using vb.net, I was following the examples in the [Autofac](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/) site, but I am getting this error:

**An exception of type 'System.MissingMemberException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll but was not handled in user code.
Additional information: Public member 'RegisterType' on type 'ContainerBuilder' not found.**

this is what I have defined in my Global.asax.vb:

```
Shared _containerProvider As IContainerProvider

Public ReadOnly Property ContainerProvider() As IContainerProvider Implements IContainerProviderAccessor.ContainerProvider
        Get
            Return _containerProvider
        End Get
    End Property
```

....

```
' Build up your application container and register your dependencies.
Dim builder = New ContainerBuilder()
builder.RegisterType(Of CustomerService)().As(Of ICustomerService)()
builder.RegisterType(Of CustomerContactService)().As(Of ICustomerContactService)()
builder.RegisterType(Of UnitOfWork)().As(Of IUnitOfWork)()


' Once you're done registering things, set the container
' provider up with your registrations.
_containerProvider = New ContainerProvider(builder.Build())
```

this is what I have in my web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="ContainerDisposal" type="Autofac.Integration.Web.ContainerDisposalModule, Autofac.Integration.Web" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
      <add name="PropertyInjection" type="Autofac.Integration.Web.Forms.PropertyInjectionModule, Autofac.Integration.Web" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
      <add name="AttributedInjection" type="Autofac.Integration.Web.Forms.AttributedInjectionModule, Autofac.Integration.Web" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

and

```
<httpModules>
  <!-- This section is used for IIS6 -->
  <add name="ContainerDisposal" type="Autofac.Integration.Web.ContainerDisposalModule, Autofac.Integration.Web"/>
  <add name="PropertyInjection" type="Autofac.Integration.Web.Forms.PropertyInjectionModule, Autofac.Integration.Web"/>
  <add name="AttributeInjection" type="Autofac.Integration.Web.Forms.AttributedInjectionModule, Autofac.Integration.Web"/>
</httpModules>
```

I added all the references via nuget [Autofac.Web](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Web)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey @reguapo - I need autofac to a legacy vb project can call some c# with ioc. Can you share how you got around having global inherit from httpapplication and IContainerProviderAccessor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `Dim builder = New ContainerBuilder()` to `Dim builder As ContainerBuilder = New ContainerBuilder()`.

The compiler does not recognize that your are calling an extension method without a strong type.

> Extension methods are not considered in late binding.

[MSDN: Extension Methods (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot @halter73, the solution was so easy that I couldn't believe it, after that everything worked perfectly

Comment: or simply `Dim builder As New ContainerBuilder()`